# MSbuild style cop extensions task to run on solution

Tags: msbuild, stylecop

I need help in running stylecop task on all cs files included in solution.
Please let me know if its possible and how?
Right now I can run it on a file, but not on solution.

```
 <CreateItem Include="$(RootPath)\**\*.cs">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="StyleCopFiles"/>
</CreateItem>

 <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.StyleCop
          TaskAction="Scan"
          ShowOutput="true"
          ForceFullAnalysis="true"
          CacheResults="false"
          SourceFiles="@(StyleCopFiles)"
          logFile="$(OutDir)\StyleCopLog.txt"
          SettingsFile="$(MSBuildStartupDirectory)\..\Settings.StyleCop"
          ContinueOnError="false">
          <Output TaskParameter="Succeeded" PropertyName="AllPassed"/>
          <Output TaskParameter="ViolationCount" PropertyName="Violations"/>
          <Output TaskParameter="FailedFiles" ItemName="Failures"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.StyleCop>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered automatically running StyleCop rules as a part of your project build process? This won't run all rules at the solution level but at a project level. I prefer this approach because the rules will run whenever you build your project/solution and will display as Warnings in the Error List panel (double click to navigate to the offending line of code). Configuring this on a project by project basis may seem like a pain but we have a different set of StyleCop rules for our Unit Test projects, and this allows us to configure them individually.

Also, You won't have to explicitly add a MSBuild task to your build script because building the projects will automatically execute the StyleCop rules.

It's also worth noting that I'm using the NuGet Package: StyleCop.MSBuild (version 4.7.17.1) and using a relative path to reference the package from within my .csproj file like this:

```
<Project>
    <Import Project="..\Packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.17.1\tools\StyleCop.targets" />
</Project>
```

http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20StyleCop%20in%20VS2005%20or%20VS%20Express&referringTitle=Documentation

You can also set conditions on when you want the rules to run. If the condition evaluates to false StyleCop will not run. We use the condition to suppress StyleCop when running Unit Tests

```
<Project>
    <Import Project="..\Packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.17.1\tools\StyleCop.targets" Condition="'$(NCrunch)'!='1'" />
</Project>
```

In order to configure StyleCop rules, you will need to install StyleCop_v4.7.17.0.msi. We only define a single Settings.StyleCop file (Parent Settings File) for our entire codebase.

http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sharing%20StyleCop%20Settings%20Across%20Projects&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Will it generate a consolidated log for all classes in one file? MsBuildExtensionpackage allows you to do so.                              http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/

Comment: We are using CruiseControl and by default it just adds to the output from the build to the main log and includes that in the main build report. So we see all the StyleCop warnings just like we would see and compilation errors. I haven't looked into displaying the warnings in its own StyleCop formatted report (if that is what you are asking) because we didn't have the need to for that step.